# Android - Fragment is popped up on the Activity Foreground

Tags: android, android-fragments

Why is this happening?

[image]

When RelativeLayout is clicked, fragment should start, but not like this. What Am I doind wrong. P.S. I am new to Fragments

Source code: DrawerActivity.java:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_del_h);

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.sss);
    rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = DelHome.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragment = new LocationPicker();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
```

Fragment.xml code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="datasite.com.aroba.LocationPicker">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

DrawerActivity.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
..........
.......
.......
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a new `Fragment` on top of what you currently have. That `Fragment` doesn't have a background, so you can just see through it.

You could add a background to the `Fragment`, or perhaps you would want to `replace` the Fragment instead?

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
```

For the layouts, this is what I have for my NavDrawer.

This is my `activity_main.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white_alpha"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here is my `app_bar_main.xml`, which contains the container I'm replacing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then when I replace an item into the container, it keeps the `Toolbar` and everything where it is.

Comment: Still, it doesnt help. actually I have one activity and want from that activity to move to fragment. after moving, the toolbar and drawer layout should not get change

Comment: I have read many posts, however, my problem is nowhere stated

Comment: I've edited my answer to give an example of what I'm doing for this. Using `replace` and my layouts, it will replace the contents of the container and put the `Fragment` in it. The toolbar and the nav drawer are not changed.

Comment: So I have to use replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment)?

Comment: No, you don't have to use `replace`, depends on your use-case. Changing Fragments with a NavDrawer - use replace. Showing a popup - use add. If you're using add, make sure your Fragment's layout has a background, and that you're adding it to the right container, the one that's below your toolbar.

In your `DrawerActivity.xml`, your `R.id.container` is the entire layout.

Answer (score 0):

Insde of your MainActivity add fragment and then replace current fragment with the another one that will be the better way of doing what you are wanted to do

you can find demo here : http://chrisrisner.com/Using-Fragments-with-the-Navigation-Drawer-Activity

Comment: In this tutorial, there is nothing related to my case. I have learnt how to move to fragment. I am doing this, but my fragment loses its background. dont know why